# Answer and Comment time-discrepancy when on question page

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, live-refresh

These two images say it all. See the **time** the comment was posted and the time answer was posted.

---

**Before Refresh (When I have been on the page for 2 mins)**

[image: Before Refresh]

---

**After Refresh (Actual Times)**

[image: After Refresh]

---

The **JavaScript** to update the comment's time does not seem to be running/present, and hence, being on the page for a while messes up comment and answer times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments weren't included with the updates for date / time.  This will be fixed in the next build.